# Java 8 signed applet not working on lower versions on Java

Tags: java, applet

I have developed an applet using Java8 and I have used a comodo code signing certificate to sign the jar. It is working perfectly.

Issue is my client cannot upgrade to Java8 as other applications they use will not work on Java8. My client uses Java7u45.

I have installed JRE7u51 on my machine and the applet is not working. I am not sure what is the issue. Help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: Hi Michael, not working means the applet is not running. Once I login into the application the code will initiate the applet. It has to be loaded on to the UI. It should open a socket in listening mode which is not happening. The enable Java console option is selected in the Java console but I still don't see the Java console. Once I jump on to Java8 it started working.